# send the parameter javascript in html

Tags: javascript

I want to send the parameter "Min" to textbox of the form "time".
but i don't know how i can do it.....

```
<html>
    <script language="javascript">
        tid = 0;
        sumcost=400;
        todaycost=50;
        var Min=(sumcost-todaycost);
        alert(Min);
    </script>

    <form name="time">
        <div align="center">
          <script language="JavaScript">
          document.write('<input style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; bo ?rder: none; color:#CC0000 ; FONT-SIZE: 14pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center;" name=result size=30 value="Minus1()">');
          </script>
        </div>
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.write('<input style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; bo ?rder: none; color:#CC0000 ; FONT-SIZE: 14pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center;" name=result size=30 value="'+Min+'">');
```